# Repositioning hidden div on ipad

Tags: javascript, ipad

I have a div that is hidden and becomes a modal-type window when the Rate Quote button is clicked.  It seems to work well on my laptop, but it doesn't position correctly on my ipad 2.  When in landscape, it doesn't show up at all.  When in portrait, it displays at the bottom of the page, below the rest of the content.

I'm not sure what is going on.  Here is the **javascript I am using**:

```
function openquote(){
var w = 425;
var h = 350;
myleft = (window.screen.width)?(window.screen.width-w)/2:100;
mytop = (window.screen.height)?(window.screen.height-h)/4:100;
window.document.getElementById('quotediv').style.marginTop = mytop + 'px';
window.document.getElementById('quotediv').style.marginLeft = myleft + 'px';
window.document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'block';
window.document.getElementById('quotediv').style.display = 'block';
```

**The CSS is:**

```
#quotediv {
display:none;
z-index:99;
height:338px;
width:323px;
position:fixed;
border-radius:10px;
border:2px solid #FFF;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #989898;
background-color:#8b0202;
}
```

You can view the page at http://www.ntxprospec.com/services.html

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the page on my browser and resized it until it suddenly disappeared from the screen, so I was able to reproduce the issue in the browser.  When I changed your margin-top and margin-left to instead be top and left, the issue went away.  The downside is the the modal is not centered even if it becomes visible, and using JavaScript to center the element is actually a bit overkill.  I recommend [this post on CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/) for how to do the same thing with just CSS.  If you use that approach, all you will need to do with the JavaScript function is the show/hide.